# Running siFR again after AJAX request

Tags: ajax, sifr

I'm using sIFR after the page has loaded to replace my headers. Now when I load some additional content into a div container using an XMLHTTP request, how can I run sIFR again to replace the headers of the added content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to run the same `sIFR.replace()` function that your script uses on startup?